# Redefining Infinity in LaTeX

Tags: math-operators

Infinity is defined as something that is uncountable. But every where I see the symbol of Infinity as a closed loop. My professor said, that it symbolizes that the boundary of Infinity is determined but it isn't so. I too agree with him. The Infinity symbol must be open curve rather than closed, something like this:
[image]
I would like to define and use this symbol for Infinity. How do I achieve it?

Comment: I can't agree with your professor's opinion. This symbol *doesn't* denote infinity when referred to sets, but just a mathematical concept used in analysis.

Comment: If you want to be understood by other mathematicians, use established symbols. Or do you also write ":" instead of "2" because the colon better represents two-hood? --That beng said, you might add a small white blob on top of the standard $\infty$ symbol (assuming you only write on white background)

Comment: Adding infinity gives a one-point compactification of the real numbers, which the closed shape nicely suggests.

Comment: I agree with @egreg (and not with your professor). It is just a symbol used traditionally.

Comment: I like that you're trying to capture intuition by changing notation, but this seems too specific to a certain interpretation. Also, you shouldn't expect to capture a symbol's meaning so specifically by how it's written. You could say $\infty$ is special in that it only ever means infinity. But on that route, why not take issue with it having an intersection point? Why doesn't $O$ mean infinity? Hmm, then what would we do about $0$? I think it's worth living with some counterintuitive notation for the sake of universal communication.

Comment: I aggree with the other users commenting saying that symbols actual form may be arbitrary and it doesnt interfere with the ability to interpret them and/or solve problems with it in them. Just think of the digit 2. It does not visually represent the discrete quantity nor the value of or purpose associated with the number. It is just an arbitrary symbol. Also infinity is when the loop is closed, infinity is the end of endless, the stop after not stopping, if u think u want to redesign infinity to be an unclosed loop then your seriously mislead smh

Answer (score 7):

Both symbols are available in Unicode:

- U+221D: ∝ PROPORTIONAL TO
- U+221E: ∞ INFINITY

It is not a good idea to replace the well-established symbol for infinity, which even many non-mathematicians will understand, by a different symbol, a relational operator, which is used for a complete different purpose. This is called obfuscating and will irritate the user at best.

Of course LaTeX can print both symbols:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}% or latexsym, amssymb, mathabx, txfonts, pxfonts, wasysym
\begin{document}
\[ \infty \propto \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

If `\propto` is used as symbol for infinity, then it needs a set of curly braces to get rid of the `\mathrel` property, e.g.:

```
\newcommand*{\myinfinity}{{\propto}}
```

Example for LuaTeX/XeTeX with Unicode math fonts. The example also shows different input methods for the symbols:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
\noindent
% Latin modern
\[ \infty \propto \]
\setmathfont{Asana-Math.otf}
\[ ∞ ∝ \]
\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}
\[ ∞ ∝ \]
\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}
\[ ^^^^221e ^^^^221d \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result LuaTeX/XeTeX]

Comment: Ugh, no, don't use \propto. It already means proportional to. That would be horribly confusing.

Comment: @EL_DON `\propto` is just the macro name as provided by the packages, no more, no less.

Comment: To clarify, don't use the proportional symbol for infinity. You may as well use 4 as a symbol for 3.

Comment: @EL_DON Then the comment belongs to the question. Only the OP and the professor of the OP want to use the proportional symbol for infinity. The first paragraph of the answer, however, votes against the off-label usage.

Comment: Other answers made an infinity symbol with a notch cut out with a white mark. While still confusing, that method answers the question without reusing another symbol exactly.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand\myinfty{{\infty%
\mathchoice%
{\llap{\color{white}\vrule width 0.2em height 0.3em depth -0.15em}}%
{\llap{\color{white}\vrule width 0.2em height 0.3em depth -0.15em}}%
{\llap{\color{white}\vrule width 0.2em height 0.22em depth -0.1em}}%
{\llap{\color{white}\vrule width 0.2em height 0.15em depth -0.09em}}%
}}
\begin{document}  
In Text: $\sum_{n=1}^\myinfty \frac1n = \myinfty$
and $\myinfty_{\myinfty_\myinfty}^{\myinfty^\myinfty} $.
In display:
\[\sum_{n=1}^\myinfty \frac1n = \myinfty\]
\[\myinfty_{\myinfty_\myinfty}^{\myinfty^\myinfty}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I took the liberty of removing the `pdftex` option to `color`, which shouldn't be given; also I changed `$$...$$` into the more correct `\[...\]`. And +1.

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own copy of used math font and you can do changes here by `fontforge` program, for example.

Or you can redefine the `\infty` macro, for example by such way:

```
\let\oriinfty=\infty
\def\infty{{\oriinfty\llap{\vrule height.24em depth-.2em width.2em}}}
```

This example does the black rule over the infinity char in the appropriate place. Now, it is your exercise to do this rule not black but white. You can use color or xcolor package and set the color statement for the `\llap{...}` part of my macro.

It is more complicated to do this working in scriptstyle and scripscriptstyle too. Read the documentation about `\mathchoice` TeX primitive for this.

Note: I don't evaluate here if this is good or bad decision to change the infinity character.